# How to open file with unsupported file extension using Java Code via the Desktop?

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have a program which reads in a file path or URI and launches what ever the file or URI via the Desktop.  The problem i'm running in to is unsupported file extensions.  The odd thing is the error I get when it fails to open the file isnt what I would expect.  The error reads

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/Users/angel/Desktop/test.test. Error message: Access is denied.

at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:77)
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:54)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:272)
at desktopopenfile.DesktopOpenFile.openFile(DesktopOpenFile.java:24)
at desktopopenfile.DesktopOpenFile.main(DesktopOpenFile.java:15)
```

I would think the error would be more along the lines of file extension unsupported.  I can verify the file extension in the other program that feeds the database which this supports but I was wondering if there was a way to allow the user to pick an application to open an unsupported file with.

My ideal solution would work similar to when you attempt to open an unsupported file in windows it ask you what program you'd like to use to open it or search the web.  I would have been good if I had gotten that option using my code below.  The idea is I want to be able to open any file type via a URI or file path.  Currently my code works with .pdf, .xml, .pptx, and word files. Any suggestions would be awesome.

```
 /**
 * Checks if a file or URI is included in the message and if so opens it via
 * the Desktop
 */
private void checkMessage() {
    // check to make sure the data model and time model are set
    if (dataModel == null || timeModel == null) {
        return;
    }

    int selectedIndex = jTable.convertRowIndexToModel(jTable.getSelectedRow());
    if (selectedIndex != -1) {
        IntData intData = dataModel.getData(selectedIndex);
        IceData iceData = ((IceData) intData);
        if (iceData != null) {
            if (iceData.getMessage() != null) {
                String message = iceData.getMessage();
                if (message != null) {
                    if (message.contains("file://")) {
                        String path = message.substring(message.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, message.indexOf(" ", message.lastIndexOf("/")));
                        openFile(path);
                    }
                    else if (message.contains("uri://")) {
                        try {
                            URI uri = new URI(message.substring(message.indexOf("/") + 2, message.indexOf(" ", message.lastIndexOf("/"))));
                            openURI(uri);
                        }
                        catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(IceDataListPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to open URI: {0}", ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Opens the file given the path
 *
 * @param path to the file
 */
private void openFile(String path) {
    try {
        File file = new File(path);

        if (file.exists()) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File Does not Exist");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IceDataListPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to open file: {0}", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Opens the URI given the URI
 *
 * @param path to the file
 */
private void openURI(URI uri) throws IOException {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the standard OS dialog asking for an application (with Java 7 and Windows 8). If you get access denied, it is probably because the user running the Java program has no right to open the file.

[image]

Test app:

```
public class DesktopOpenFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFile("huhu.orttr");
    }

    private static void openFile(String path) {
        try {
            File file = new File(path);

            if (file.exists()) {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("DesktopOpenFile::openFile: file = " + file.getAbsolutePath() + (file.exists() ? " - exists" : " - does not exist!"));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you run my test program?

Comment: I get the same error as I did before 

java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/C:/Users/angel/Desktop/test.test. Error message: Access is denied.

 at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:77)
 at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(WDesktopPeer.java:54)
 at java.awt.Desktop.open(Desktop.java:272)
 at desktopopenfile.DesktopOpenFile.openFile(DesktopOpenFile.java:24)
 at desktopopenfile.DesktopOpenFile.main(DesktopOpenFile.java:15)

Comment: Maybe the file is open and locked in another app. Anyway, as you see, the code itself is running as expected on my machine, something must be wrong with your setup...

Comment: It works fine if you open a file with an extension it can handle it doesnt work on a file with an extension it doesnt know what to do with.  It has nothing to do with the file being locked or open in another fashion.  I've created multiple files on the desktop to test this with different extensions and all work except unsupported extensions.

Comment: Please think about the fact that the *same code* works as expected on my machine (as you can see from the screenshot): it *can* can handle extensions that are not registered with the operating system and no exceptions are thrown. How do you explain that?

Comment: You are correct in the fact that my code works on windows 8 and ask what what application you'd like to use to open the file.  However it doesnt work on windows XP, Vista, or 7.  Havent tried it yet on Linux.  That being said I'm looking for a solution that works on older versions of windows not just windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [JDIC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jdic-assoc-136531.html) file type associations.

```
AssociationService serv = new AssociationService();
Association logassoc = serv.getFileExtensionAssociation("LOG"); // .log ?
if (logassoc == null) {
    return; // .log not a registered file type.
}
```

Comment: I can see using this as a way to manage if the extension is supported however I keep getting the error 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jdic in java.library.path at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860) at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845) at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)

Comment: After some researches I am no longer sure JDIC is sufficiently active. That would be very sad. An UnsatisfiedLinkError could come from only having 32 bits DLLs; one must run a 32 bits JVM. Sorry, I thought JDIC would have evolved under org.jdesktop.